# how do you unrotate a child element if its parent element is rotated?

Tags: css, css-transforms

The goal is to have the child element rotated by its parent element but once you click the child element it animates to how it would be if there were no rotates applied to the parent element. So basically I am just trying to take the rotates from the parent element off.

```
WIN - rotateZ(ndeg) on the parent and rotateZ(-ndeg) on the child
FAIL - rotateXY(ndeg) on the parent and rotateXY(-ndeg) on the child
```

[image]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arGWr/)

Answer (score 1):

To understand, the the child of the rotated divs are making their transformation from their parents point, so from rotateX(50) the child is doing a rotateX(-50) from "0" but it isn't "0" persay, which won't give you what you are expecting.

What you need to do is wrap everything and treat them separately so that the "parent" doesn't actually affect the child. Then you can reverse it properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/arGWr/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="outerX"></div>
    <div class="inner1X"></div>
    <div class="inner2X"></div>
</div>
```

edit: to better explain, in the original solution, you have a square. It changes to a rectangle, now when you do a rotate on that - it's doing it on the rectangle, compounding on the rotate. It doesn't know you are trying to reverse a previous transformation.

Comment: this does get the child element unrotated but now it doesn't get rotated by the parent element at all. im trying to make it rotated by the parent but then when you click the child it rotates back to the position it would be in if there were no rotate done to the parent. i modified your fiddle to illustrate. the child should be moving with the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/arGWr/2/

Comment: please ignore my last comment. this is what i meant to say -- the outer element is the wrapper. im trying to figure out how to rotate the outer element and have the child elements rotated along with it but then when you click one of the child elements it animates to the position it would be in if there were no rotate done to the parent element.

Comment: So you don't know how to do the click event?

Comment: of course i know how to do the click event. the child element has to rotate with the parent. then the child element has to animate to how it would be if the parent were not rotated (but the parent should be rotated). they were in a wrapper in the original example (.outer, .inner)

Comment: You cannot do them "together" you must rotate individually in the format I showed you otherwise they will be distorted and you won't be able to "revert".

Comment: Yes you can dave. they are rotated together in the very first fiddle i posted. i dont think you understand the question. thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding this to the parent

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

Reference: http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/transform-style.html